# peerServer is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, backend, peerjs, peer

```
const { peerServer } = require("peer");
const ExpressPeerServer = peerServer(server, {
  debug: true,
});
```

> TypeError: const { peerServer } = require("peer")(app);
> ^  **peerServer is not a function**

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXNMm.png) is an image of the log message

Comment: you invoking and passing app, `const { peerServer } = require("peer");` is not the same as  `const { peerServer } = require("peer")(app);`

Comment: I try both but both of them give me the same error

Comment: re/read the docs there is an example https://www.npmjs.com/package/peer#combining-with-existing-express-app

Answer (score 0):

p should be capital when you are destructing peer import.
so replace `const { peerServer } = require("peer");` with `const { PeerServer } = require('peer');`